# ClearCase Snapshot Views: exclude one particular directory from load statements?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

Good morning,

is there any way to exclude only one particular directory from a snapshot's load statement, e.g. I want to load a whole vob named '*PM_CT*' **except** the \PM_CT\lost+found directory

... is there an elegant way to do it? And how would I generally exclude all *lost+found* directories across multiple loaded vobs?

Cheers and Thanks,

-Jörg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
element /PM_CT/lost+found -none
```

The "elegant" way consists of:

- adding a *selection* rule (here "`-none`")
- loading *all* PM_CT without aking any question (`load /PM_CT`), if your view is a snapshot one

Note: in a config spec, always use "/": it is easier, and Windows as well as Unix ClearCase views will be able to interpret it.

Caveats:

- the previous solution is for one vob, I do not think you could use "wildcard" for multiple vobs
- the '`-none`' option can cause a **snapshot** view to fail during a deliver or rebase (UCM merge): for that kind of operation, a dynamic view would be more suited. That is for CC 2003.06 and early 7.0. I think it works better with the latest CC7.1.0.2

Note: that selection rule can also be used for dynamic views, in order to mask some directory you would not want to see.

Answer (score 15):

*I would like to make an addition to the previously posted answer:*

### The lost+found directories

To exclude the lost+found directories across all VOBs you can modify the previously proposed selection rule to be more generic:

```
#Skip the lost+found directories
element .../lost+found -none
```

However, using the '-none' flag causes the Windows ClearCase client to list errors when updating a snapshot view:

> Unable to load "lost+found": no version selected in configuration specification. 
>   Unable to load "lost+found".

It also does not properly unload any previously loaded folders or files, so you may need to recreate your snapshot view (or unload/reload the VOB) with the new selection rule if you really want to clean out the lost+found directories...

### Elegance

For excluding any normal folder, the "elegant way" would be to specifically load the **/main/0** version of the folder:

```
#Exclude the contents of a directory
element /VOB_name/folder_path /main/0
```

This will cause the folder to be loaded as empty and will not produce an error. It will also properly unload any loaded files. It unfortunately does *not* work for the lost+found directory, because it is always listed as version /main/0.

Comment: The errors generated by "-none" are unfortunate because they are noise which can mask true errors. One way I see to avoid them is to create a special directory version completely without the "-none" elements. But then one runs into issues when others change the original directory version. Any suggestions?