# Can cleartool make a snapshot view with load rules?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

Is there a way to automatically create view with its load rules with `cleartool` command line?

Right now I'm using: 'cleartool mkview' command and after that I am adding each vob as a load rule (wrote a script for that).

I wanted to know if there is a better solution to load the vobs automatically right after creating the view (as it is done when I create the view from Project Explorer GUI) .. ?

Answer (score 1):

No: by default a snapshot view (UCM or not) doesn't load anything, because it has no idea of the size of the update, it could very well be more than your hard drive has space for.

Your script remains the best option.

For UCM views, I prefer getting the root folders of all components in a stream (as in "[how to find root[folder] for each component using `cleartool`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8769988/6309)"), and add those paths as load rules.
If your components are vob-component though, adding the all vob as a load rule is enough.

I also exclude (in the config spec "`UCMCustomElemBegin/End` " part) the [`vob/lost+found` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1205675/6309) (which you would not if you were to load the full vob)

```
element /yourVob/lost+found -none
```

That way, I can load the all vob without getting the `lost+found` folder (present in each vob), which can [prevents merge to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22360388/6309).